# Changing image url based on broswer width with existing code

Tags: javascript, php, image, resize

I'm new at JavaScript so please forgive me if this question has been asked.

I want to make my `img` tag responsive so I'm using this:

```
<img data-nsrc="<?php 
                 echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id()
                                                 , 'small-post'
                                                 , false )[0] ?>"
     data-msrc="<?php 
                 echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id()
                                                 , 'mobile-img', false )[0] ?>"
     src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id()
                                                , 'small-post'
                                                , false )[0] ?>" 
     class="img-right resimgsm">
```

I changed the code to use an `img` as before I was using a `div` with `inline CSS` and a `background image`.

This is `script` running at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( window ).resize(function(ev) {
      var w=jQuery( window ).width();
      if(w>600){
        jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
            jQuery(el).attr('src',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-nsrc')+"')")
        })
      }else{
        jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
            jQuery(el).attr('src',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-msrc')+"')")
        })
      }
    });
    jQuery(window).trigger('resize')
})  
</script>
```

Can someone walk me through on how to change this?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not seeing any code that shows you've attempted Browser detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the image source is very similar to what you previously had, you need only the direct image URL:

```
  if(w>600){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('src',jQuery(el).attr('data-nsrc'))
    })
  }else{
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('src', jQuery(el).attr('data-msrc'))
    })
  }
```

---

Short explanation

What you previously had probably looked like:

```
<div style="background-image: url(imageURLHere.jpg);"></div>
```

and you were modifying the style attribute or the CSS property.

What you have now should look like:

```
<img src="imageURLHere.jpg">
```

and the code above does that.

Comment: One more question: In `jQuery('.resimgsm')`, If I wanted to change multiple classes, do I add a comma like `jQuery('.resimgsm','.otherclass')` or make it an array like `jQuery(array('.resimgsm','.otherclass'))`?

Comment: You add comma within the string: `jQuery('.resimgsm, .otherclass')`. You're welcome.